# Repeated column in mapping for entity with @ManytoOne annotation and another referencedColumnName

Tags: java, hibernate

```
I have a problem with my mapping OneToMany. My exception is
```

org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.lcdut.model.SubjectsModel column: groups (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "subjects")
public class SubjectsModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "groups")
    private int groups;
    ...........
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="groups", referencedColumnName="id_group")
    })
    private StudentsModel studentsModel;
    ........
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class StudentsModel{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "pib")
    private String pib;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "id_group")
    ........
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "studentsModel")
    private Set<SubjectsModel> subjects;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You've told Hibernate that the value for the `groups` column comes from both the primitive property `groups` as well as the relational mapping `studentsModel`.  That is illegal and only one can influence the value.

You either need to specify the `groups` mapping as:

```
@Column(name = "groups", insertable = false, updatable = false)
```

or you can specify that `studentsModel` is:

```
@JoinColumn(
  name = "groups", 
  referencedColumnName = "id_group", 
  insertable = false, 
  updatable = false
)
```

or lastly remove the primitive property and influence the value solely through the relational `@ManyToOne` mapping without having to change your annotations.

Comment: Then I have errors, I had tried it before(((

Comment: Then there is something else going wrong because if you intend to map the same column to multiple mappings in an entity, you can only have one of them influence the insert/update settings.

Comment: Linking to this answer as it is precisely the same as mine to the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42076333/1572269