# Hibernate: Repeated Column in Mapping

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, mapping

So in this example scenario I have an attendance DTO, and a worker DTO, workers in this context are separated by department, and a worker can only ever be inside of one department. It is important to note that `Worker {id='123-123-123', department='a'}` is different to `Worker {id='123-123-123', department='b'}`, despite them both sharing the same Id.

I have the following class setup to try and separate functions by `id` and `department`

```
public class IdAndDepartmentPK implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String department;

    public IdAndDepartmentPK() {}
    ...
}
```

This key class is shared between DTOs that require both the `Worker`'s `id` and `department`, below are the two DTOs that are causing a problem.

```
@Entity
@IdClass(IdAndDepartmentPK.class)
public class AttendencetDto {

    @Id private String id; // This is a departmentally unique attendenceId
    @Id private String department;
    @Column private String workerId;

    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "workerId"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "department")
    })
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private WorkerDto workerDto;
    ....
 }

 @Entity
 @IdClass(IdAndDepartmentPK.class)
 public class WorkerDto {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Id
    private String department;
    ...
 }
```

`WorkerDto` does not need to have knowledge of `AttendencetDto`, but `AttendencetDto`, does need to have access to `WorkerDto` and the other data it contains.

Hibernate complains that fields like `workerId` should be mapped with insert="false" update="false", but if I was to do this then I wouldn't be able to persist those values to the database.

I essentially want to have those fields available whilst also having the `WorkerDto` available, is this possible?

Comment: Why you need ` @Column private String workerId;`? You can link your entity by workerDto.

Comment: But if I have the table `attendence` for instance, with column `worker_id`, would hibernate insert the data there without me specifying that column in the dto?

Comment: If there is a connection on a foreign key, you can just set `workerDto` and after transaction is closed your entities will be linked.

Comment: Actually, you're right, that is working as expected. Cheers dude.

Comment: please marked my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `@Column private String workerId;` because you already map it by relation to `WorkerDto`.

If you want to create relation between that you should use `setWorkerDto` method in your `AttendencetDto` and just save. After transaction ends you will have your relation in DB.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it the correct resolution!